# Ruby on Rails - Devise login is case sensitive in production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails app that is using Devise perfectly in development. I have altered it, following the official Devise documentation to use a username instead of an email address. I am also using MySQL, instead of SQLite.

When logging in, in development, I can type in "admin" to login as the user "Admin". But in production, "admin" does not work and requires me to type in the case sensitive "Admin".

I'm assuming it's a different setting in my MySQL database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you have an attribute for logging in called `login`. If it's `username`, use that instead of `login` below. In your Devise initializer, there is a setting:

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
```

Change to

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email, :login ]
```

This will:

> These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.

So, you might need to update the Admin's login once, but then if you type in Admin or admin, it will find and authenticate.

Comment: A bit of a late response, but thanks for your help! This was what worked for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally for devise we do something on the following manner. Can you check whether this is the case in your AdminUser model

```
validates :email,:presence => true,
    :format => {:with=>email_regex,:message => "not a valid email"},
    :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
```